# how to store user profile pictures in springboot rest api backend application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-restcontroller

I am working in backend part with spring boot and rest api. I need to store user details in database. The question is what is best approach to handle user profile pictures in the server. how to use @POST AND @GET methods in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `POST` to store the picture on the server, `GET` to receive it and display it to the user.

**Update**
You could try something like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/image/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addImage(@RequestBody Image image) {
        imageService.addImage(image);
    }
```

This is what you put inside your controller. Then you need an `imageService`-instance which stores the image in the database. And you have an `Image`-class that contains the image data (image comes in e.g. as a base64-encoded String).

Comment: thank you, but it is not the question, picture is not just data in java, so there should be some class which handles files like Multipartfile as I know, but i asked how to use it inside  post and get methods

Comment: what have you tried? where is your source code? have you explored anything related to fileupload using rest api in google search.

Comment: @shukrat see my updated answer